# Cellular Network database

Tags: data-request, network-structure, telecom

I'm looking for a world wide database of Cellular Network Providers With the Network Id, Name and possibly a logo or graphic representing the Service provider

Can anyone point me to a source.

Answer (score 3):

This is a list of mobile phone network and satellite phone network operators measured by number of subscribers which is free in wikipedia with [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_network_operators)

Furthermore, there are a few more paid services in any case:

1) [researchandmarkets.com](http://www.researchandmarkets.com/reports/2139568/worldwide_mobile_network_operators_directory_2013)

2) [deveo](http://www.deveo.net/index.asp?id=14)

Comment: Yep, thanks, saw that but I need it in a database. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

It's very unlikely that there's a comprehensive open collection with the information you're looking for.  At the very least, logos or graphics are going to be tricky, as they're the copyright of the individual companies.

I can't answer the rest of the question with a single source, as there are at least 6 registration entities in the U.S. alone.  From the CDMA Development Group's [Document 130 (PRLs)](http://www.cdg.org/members_only/refdocs/130.zip):

> The FCC eliminated the use of SIDs and the SID assignment process in its entirety as part of
>   the license application and as a part of the FCC Year 2000 Biennial Regulatory Review
>   (Amendment of Part 22 of the Commission’s Rules to Modify or Eliminate Outdated Rules
>   Affecting the Cellular Radiotelephone Service and other Commercial Mobile Radio Services, WT
>   Docket No. 01-108, Report and Order, FCC 02-229 (released Sept. 24, 2002), the section 22.941
>   of the Commission Rules, 47 C.F.R. § 22.941).

[IFAST (International Forum on
ANSI-41 Technology)](http://www.ifast.org) might have it, but they charge:

> An Excel spreadsheet with more detailed IRM (SID) information is available to IFAST members. Membership is free to IRM/SID assignees upon application, and costs $1000 per year to others. For more information contact IFASTSec@ifastltd.org .